# jQuery check if element has a specific style property defined inline

Tags: jquery, css, inline-styles

I need to check whether an element has a defined css property given to it, but I'm having some trouble using the jQuery.css() function.

The property I'm looking for is width.

If the element does not have a defined width and I try this:

```
if(base.$element.css('width') !== 'undefined')
```

I get the browser's computed width.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Here's a very simple (probably in much need of improvement) plugin I've thrown together that will get you the value of an inline style property (and return `undefined` if that property is not found):

```
​(function ($) {
    $.fn.inlineStyle = function (prop) {
         var styles = this.attr("style"),
             value;
         styles && styles.split(";").forEach(function (e) {
             var style = e.split(":");
             if ($.trim(style[0]) === prop) {
                 value = style[1];           
             }                    
         });   
         return value;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

You can call it like this:

```
//Returns value of "width" property or `undefined`
var width = $("#someElem").inlineStyle("width");
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/eYGr5/1/).

Note that it will only return the value for the *first element* in the matched set.

Since it returns `undefined` when that style property is not found, you can use it in your situation like this:

```
if (base.$element.inlineStyle("width")) {
    // It has a `width` property!
}
```

---

**Update**

Here's a much, much shorter version. I realised that `prop("style")` returns an object, not a string, and the properties of that object correspond to the available style properties. So you can just do this:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.inlineStyle = function (prop) {
        return this.prop("style")[$.camelCase(prop)];
    };
}(jQuery));
```

You may want to replace the use of `$.camelCase` with a custom camelcase function, since the jQuery one appears to be undocumented and is probably not good to rely upon. I just used it here as it's shorter.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/eYGr5/2/) of that one. Note that in this case, the return value will be the empty string if the style was not found on the element. That will still evaluate to `false`, so the above `if` statement should still work.

Comment: Great ..first i though of some reg-ex based solutions..if this work then its great !!

Comment: @MatthewGrima - I've updated my answer with a much shorter version of that plugin code. Might be worth testing that in a few different browsers though - I've only tried it in Chrome.

Answer (score 27):

Why not just:

```
var $el = $('element[style*="width"]');
```

And then you can test it with:

```
if ( $el.length ) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: I like it, but this solution will also match 'min-width' and 'max-width', which may be problematic if specifically looking for non-hyphenated 'width'.

Answer (score 10):

Checking for "width" for example:

```
if ($(element).prop("style")["width"] !== '')
{...}
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `.attr` to check the `style` attribute.

```
if(base.$element.attr('style').length > 0) {
   //...
}
```

If you care about the width, then

```
if(base.$element.attr('style').indexOf('width') !== -1) {
   //...
}
```

Comment: But how does this check if it has width ?

Comment: I don't actually care if the element has other styles, I need to know if it has a width defined inside the style attribute.

Comment: @ubercooluk The op only need to check whether has an inline-style. If you want to check `width`, then could do something like `.indexOf('width') !== -1`

Comment: I'll change the question title, but the content of the question is quite clear

Comment: @ubercooluk If it's defined in a CSS definition (either in an external CSS file or a `<style>` tag) then it's not, by definition, inline.

Comment: @xdazz - What if there was, for example, a `border-width` property but no `width` property?

Answer (score -3):

Matthew you can check if style attribute is undefined or not

```
    var attr = $(this).attr('style');
    if (typeof attr !== 'undefined' ) {
   }
```

Comment: This is not what the question is asking. It is asking to determine if a `width` has been defined in the `style` attribute.