# How to get image height property

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can i find if image has no height style property.

Css in Html

```
<img id="image" src="images/sports/sports9.png" style="width:100px">
```

Jquery

```
 if($('#image').css('height') == 0)
    {
        var imageWidth = $("#image").width();
        $("#image").css("width",""+(imageWidth-1)+"px");
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){...});`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var img = document.getElementById('image');
if( !img.style.height) img.style.width = img.width-1+"px";
```

Comment: Sometimes people forget regular javascript still exists. (I'm guilty of this as well)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you are after?

http://binodsuman.blogspot.se/2009/06/how-to-get-height-and-widht-of-image.html

Or do you mean that you would like to check if the image has a *height* property set or not?

**Update:**

Check here for a similar question

[jQuery check if element has a specific style property defined inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306736/jquery-check-if-element-has-a-specific-style-property-defined-inline)