# Convert all 'display: none' to display block in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML web page wherein I need to find out all the elements having the `display:none` and style them to `display:block` using a script, which I can write in console or using Firebug.

There is already a script present for showing all the hidden elements in form tags. I need a similar script for `display:none` to `display:block`.

```
   var snapHidden = document.evaluate("//input[@type='hidden']",
       document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
   for (var i = snapHidden.snapshotLength - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
       var elmHidden = snapHidden.snapshotItem(i);
       elmHidden.style.MozOutline = '1px dashed #666';
       elmHidden.type = 'text';
       elmHidden.title = 'Hidden field "' +
           (elmHidden.name || elmHidden.id) + '"';
   }
```

Comment: is the `display:none` added via a common css file? Or via `style=display:none` tags? If via style tags, do you intend to show  only these times to block, or anything that's hidden?

Comment: Maybe this helps: [Can jQuery get all CSS styles associated with an element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element#answer-5830517) .... Use that script to get the `display:none` style and add `.show()`to those elements if they have that style in it's attribute.

Comment: The code you posted is unrelated to your question. Please edit your question and post the code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$('*').filter(function(){
   return $(this).css('display') == 'none';
}).css('display', 'block')
```

Comment: Not working for the page I am trying. Need to convert only the display:none and not all the elements

Comment: @Rahul That's what doing this answer, have you tried it? If not working as expected, please provide concrete sample

Comment: One downside, what about SPAN with `display: none;` set? You'd have better to use jQuery `.show()` method i guess to hanlde inline elements. But for sure OP question doesn't make much sense imho

Comment: I didn't use `show` because OP wanted `display:block`

Comment: @Musa But i guess OP not really knows what to expect. Setting `display:block` on inline elements is a layout killer

Answer (score 1):

```
    $('body').find(':hidden').each(function(){
       $(this).show();
    });
```

Hope this helps.
Thanks

Comment: Nope.It shows a blank array since I guess its just taking for document object alone and not all the elements

Answer (score -1):

Here's a working solution. The first function in the javascript is taken from this stackoverflow page: [jquery-check-if-element-has-a-specific-style-property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306736/jquery-check-if-element-has-a-specific-style-property-defined-inline#answer-11306872)

HTML:

```
<div id="list1">a_1</div>
<div id="list2">a_2</div>
<div id="list3" style="display:none;">a_3</div>
<div id="list4">b_1</div>
<div id="list5">b_2</div>
<div id="list6" style="display:none;">b_3</div>
<div id="list7">c_1</div>
<div id="list8" style="display:none;">c_2</div>
<div id="list9" style="display:none;">c_3</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
 (function ($) {
    $.fn.inlineStyle = function (prop) {
         var styles = this.attr("style"),
             value;
         styles && styles.split(";").forEach(function (e) {
             var style = e.split(":");
             if ($.trim(style[0]) === prop) {
                 value = style[1];           
             }                    
         });   
         return value;
    };
}(jQuery));



 $(document).ready( function() {

  $('*:hidden').each(function(){

    var display_prop = $(this).inlineStyle("display");
    if(display_prop){
    $(this).show();
    }
   });

 });
```

FIDDLE: [http://jsfiddle/d1oae3cL/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/mohitk117/d1oae3cL/1/)