# get style property value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="a"></div>

.a{
padding:10px;
background:red;
}
```

it's easy to get above element's background value, just use `$('.a').css('background');`

but now I have this div :

```
<div style="padding:0;background:red"></div>
```

How can I get the background property?

Comment: You have it backwards. `.css('background')` will work with the second DIV, not the first one.

Comment: So you say that this, $('div').css('background'); doesn't works for you?

Comment: Look at the answer for this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306736/jquery-check-if-element-has-a-specific-style-property-defined-inline

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle):

```
getComputedStyle($('div')[0]).background;
```

From the MDN article:

> The object returned from getComputedStyle is read-only and can be used to inspect the element's style (including those set by a  element or an external stylesheet). The elt.style object should be used to set styles on a specific element.

Comment: @JamesLemon That gets the DOM element out of the jQuery object. Because `getComputedStyle` is a DOM function, not part of jQuery.